# How can I log in to my Wikipedia account and access my watch list?

Tags: import, web-access

Wikipedia's "Edit Watchlist" page (for logged in users) has a list of hyperlinks to the user's watchlist (here is an example from my account).

[image]

I've tried to use `URLFetch` and `URLSave` as follows

```
URLFetch["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:EditWatchlist"]
URLSave["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:EditWatchlist","test.html"]
```

but it seems that they cannot grab the links in the watchlist. I thought `URLSave` is the same as saving a webpage as a HTML file by hand in Internet Explorer... Am I wrong?

Even `Import`, with

```
Import["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:EditWatchlist","Hyperlinks"]
```

(and also with `"Source"`), cannot get the hyperlinks.

How can I log into Wikipedia and get these links using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Do you have to login to that site?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, logged user could favorite pages.

Comment: Well if you need to login then `Import` is never going to work. You need to show us what code you have tried -- obviously replace actual user name and password with generic strings.

Comment: It seems to me that that page, which looks personalized to me, depends on the presence of a cookie set in your browser, which, on it's turn, depends on you being logged in. Obviously, this is not something you can do directly in Mathematica.

Comment: @Fine, there is some example in the Help Page, show pass password and ... it's limited.

Comment: Here is how to retrieve a Wikipedia user's watchlist by using the MediaWiki API. My watchlist has over 10,000 articles and it gets the full list in a few seconds (the API paging gives you 500 results at a time). http://pastebin.com/0Q6LJM9r

Comment: @MichaelHale wow, I think this could be an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHale This does not returns hyperlinks, I'm not sure whether the name in the url links are the same as that in the watchlist.  `Multinomial theorem` and `(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) `, wish could develop, even if couldn't it's also useful

Comment: FWIW; I actually think it should be possible, given the capabilities of `URLFetch`, to grab a page as a logged in user. Using for example the Chrome dev tool one can view all the headers and cookies it uses and then recreate that exact same request using `URLFetch`. Lots of work though, since the dev tool doesn't give e.g. cookies in the MMA list format.

Comment: As for logging in, I managed to do it once (sounds fishy but I think so). But then for some reason it stopped working. The options I used were `"UserAgent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) \
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 \
Safari/537.36",
"Method" -> "POST",
"Parameters" -> {"wpName" -> "username", "wpPassword1" -> "password"}` and the URL `http://en.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&action=\
submitlogin&type=login`. But now it seems Wikipedia has figured out, despite of this, I'm not using a real web browser and stops me.

Comment: @MichaelHale Just curious: why do you have such an extreme watch list?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries One reason is useful now, and the other might be more useful in the future. For now, I occasionally like to go on vandalism cleaning sprees to relieve stress. It is fun to click undo when people are damaging something so valuable. I hope in the future to be able to use my watchlist change feed to keep up to date on very specific research topics (at a finer level of topic granularity than science news sites). I'll add my response as an answer.

Comment: @HyperGroups I will convert them to links in the answer I post here. You can just URL encode them, which I have a utility function for. I think Mathematica has an undocumented function for it, but I just keep my own until the official one shows up in documentation search.

Comment: @MichaelHale I see, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MediaWiki API is good, fast, well-tested, and is usable within Mathematica for tasks that require authentication by using URLFetch. To login you need to send two POSTs. The second sends back a token that you receive from the first request. Then Mathematica automatically sets $HTTPCookies. This login function will be added to the utilities for the [Wikicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aWakebrdkid/Wikicode) project. Then you can request your watchlist once your Mathematica client has been authenticated. I use a loop to retrieve paged results if your watchlist is longer than 500 pages.

```
(* Returns True or False for success or failure *)
Login[username_String, password_String] := 
 Module[{url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", 
   parameters = {"action" -> "login", "lgname" -> username, 
     "lgpassword" -> password, "format" -> "json"}}, 
  MatchQ["result" /. ("login" /. 
      ImportString[
       If[MatchQ[#, "NeedToken"], 
          URLFetch[url, "Method" -> "POST", 
           "Parameters" -> Append[parameters, "lgtoken" -> #2]], 
          Return@False] & @@ ({"result", 
           "token"} /. ("login" /. 
            ImportString[
             URLFetch[url, "Method" -> "POST", 
              "Parameters" -> parameters], "JSON"])), "JSON"]), 
   "Success"]]

urlEncode[string_String] := 
 StringReplace[string, 
  c : Except@
     Flatten@{CharacterRange @@@ {{"A", "Z"}, {"a", "z"}, {"0", "9"}},
        Characters["-_.~"]} :> 
   StringJoin[
    "%" <> IntegerString[#, 16] & /@ ToCharacterCode[c, "UTF-8"]]]

(* retrieve watchlist and create hyperlinks *)
Hyperlink[#, "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" <> urlEncode@#] & /@ 
 Replace["title", 
  Flatten[Replace["watchlistraw", 
    Rest@NestWhileList[
      ImportString[
        URLFetch[
         "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=\
watchlistraw&format=json&wrlimit=500" <> 
          If[Length@# > 1, "&wrcontinue=" <> #[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]], 
           ""]], "JSON"] &, {}, Length@# != 1 &]], 1]]
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to get this page by mathematica?
http://index.baidu.com/?tpl=crowd&word=what
needs login.

Comment: Would you happen to know if the above can be modified to access the close-history pages of mathematica.SE (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/close/history)?